# arrangements of letters $p,q,r,s$ such that every next letter does not follow previous letter

Tags: combinatorics

Arrangement of the letters $p,q,r,s$ such that $q$ does not follow

$p$ and $r$ does not follow $q$ and $s$ does not follow r, is

Attempt :: total arrangement of $p,q,r,s$ is $4!$

let $A$ be the ways in which $q$ does not follow $p$

and  $B$ be the ways in which $r$does not follow $q$

and  $C$ be the ways in which $s$ does not follow $r$

could some help me how to solve it, thanks

Comment: Your initial statement and subsequent analysis do not quite match: "$p$ (and $r$) does not follow $q$" *or* "the ways $q$ does not follow $p$" -- which is correct?

Comment: Joffan: it’s a matter of bad typesetting; you’re missing “$q$ does not follow” on the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you would like to use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

If there were no restrictions, there would be $4!$ arrangements of the four letters p, q, r, s.  From these, we must exclude those arrangements in which q follows p, r follows q, or s follows q.

Let $A$ be the set of arrangements in which q follows p.

Let $B$ be the set of arrangements in which r follows q.

Let $C$ be the set of arrangements in which s follows r.

One pair of consecutive letters:

We count arrangements in which q follows p.  We treat pq as a single object, which leaves up with three objects to arrange, namely pq, r, and s.  They can be arranged in $3!$ orders.  By symmetry, there are $3!$ arrangements in which r follows q and $3!$ arrangements in which s follows r.

Hence, $|A| = |B| = |C| = 3!$.

Two pairs of consecutive letters:

Suppose q follows p and r follows q.  Then the arrangement must contain pqr.  This leaves us with two objects to arrange, pqr and s.  They can be arranged in $2!$ orders.

Suppose q follows p and s follows r.  Then we have two objects to arrange, namely pq and rs.  They can be arranged in $2!$ orders.

Suppose r follows q and s follows r.  Then then arrangement must contain qrs.  This leaves with two objects to arrange, p and qrs.  They can be arranged in $2!$ orders.

Hence, $|A \cap B| = |A \cap C| = |B \cap C| = 2!$.

Three pairs of consecutive letters:

If q follows p, r follows q, and s follows r, we must have pqrs, which can be arranged in $1!$ ways.

Hence, $|A \cap B \cap C| = 1!$.

The Inclusion-Exclusion Principle tells us that 
$$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$$
Hence, the number of arrangements in which at least one of the conditions is violated is 
\begin{align*}
|A \cup B \cup C| & = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|\\
& = 3! + 3! + 3! - 2! - 2! - 2! + 1!\\
& = 3 \cdot 3! - 3 \cdot 2! + 1!
\end{align*}
so the number of arrangements in which none of the conditions is violated is 
$$|(A \cup B \cup C)^C| = 4! - (3 \cdot 3! - 3! \cdot 2! + 1!) = 4! - 3 \cdot 3! + 3 \cdot 2! - 1! = 11$$

Answer (score 2):

- If we start with **p**, there are two arrangements:

  - We can pick **r** second, forcing **prqs** (since $p\color{red}{rs}q$ is invalid.)
  - Or we can pick **s** second, forcing **psrq**.
- If we start with **q**, there are three arrangements:

  - We can pick **p** second, forcing **qpsr**.
  - Or we can pick **s** second, allowing **qsrp** or **qspr**.
- If we start with **r**, there are three arrangements:

  - We can pick **p** second, forcing **rpsq**.
  - Or we can pick **q** second, allowsing **rqps** or **rqsp**.
- If we start with **s**, there are three arrangements:

  - We can pick **p** second, forcing **sprq**.
  - We can pick **q** second, forcing **sqpr**.
  - We can pick **r** second, forcing **srqp**.

That’s 11 arrangements in total.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: So we cannot have arrangements where $PQ,QR,RS$ is there. So we are allowed to take pairs like $PR,PS,QP,QS,RP,RQ,SP,SQ,SR$.

Total there will be $11$ possible arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by " $q$ does not follow
$p$"? Will $q$ not seat immediately after $p$ or $q$ can't seat after $p$ anywhere? For the first case the answer is already given. 
For the second case answer will be $3$. Total arrangement is $24$. For $12$ arrangements $p$ will seat before $q$ and in other $12$ arrangements $q$ will seat before $p$. Now continue the same logic . $12/2=6$ and $6/2=3$ .